Custom function to check blank inputs
Trying to build a custom function that checks for errors and then shows the error.
As of right now, the whole process looks like this:
$("#addRecordSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let errors = "";

  let addobj = {
    addReference: $("#addReference").val(),
    addAccount: $("#addAccount").val(),
    addDescription: $("#addDescription").val(),
    // some more items
  };

  if (addobj.addReference == "") {
    $("#addReferenceError").show();
    errors = errors + 1;
  }
  if (addobj.addAccount == "") {
    $("#addAccountError").show();
    errors = errors + 1;
  }
  if (addobj.addDescription == "") {
    $("#addDescriptionError").show();
    errors = errors + 1;
  }
  // some more if statements

  if (errors > 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    // process submit
  }
});

So a reusable function would help me out here.
So I started to build a reusable function outside of the on click function above.  It currently looks like this:
function checkFormErrors(obj, errorMessage) {
  if(obj == "") {
    $(errorMessage).show();
    errors = errors + 1;
  }
  return errors;
}

Then inside my on click function, I am calling the checkFormErrors function like this:
checkFormErrors(addobj.addReference, "#addReferenceError");

Upon submitting the form, I am getting the console error:
ReferenceError: errors is not defined

What did I do wrong, and how can I make this function work properly?
*** EDIT ***
So I'm passing "errors" from the on click into the checkFormErrors function like so:
$("#addRecordSubmit").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let errors = "";

  let addobj = {
    addReference: $("#addReference").val(),
    addAccount: $("#addAccount").val(),
    addDescription: $("#addDescription").val(),
    // some more items
  }

  checkFormErrors(addobj.addReference, "#addReferenceError", errors);

  if (errors > 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    // process submit
  }
});

So the checkFormErrors function now looks like this:
function checkFormErrors(obj, errorMessage, errors) {
  if(obj == "") {
    $(errorMessage).show();
    errors = errors + 1;
  }
  return errors;
}

I'm no longer getting the "error is not defined" message, but I am not getting the error count returned back into the on click function.
How can I fix this?

let errors = ""; sets the scope inside the onclick function, but you're trying to reference it from checkFormErrors(); you may need to set it as a global variable or pass it to checkFormErrors()

@mykaf - I updated the question to include your suggestion.

Your click listener doesn't seem to call checkFormErrors(). Where are you expecting to see this ? Also, please edit your code here to reflect changes made.

@mykaf - I did update the code underneath where it reads EDIT.  I am trying to return the count of errors into the on click function.  I hope that makes sense.

You're showing a line where you call that function, but there's no context as to where/when you are calling it. If you don't call it from within your click listener, it can't be returned to there.

@mykaf - I specified that the function call was in the click listener because I wasn't trying to readd all of the same code, but I went ahead and updated the code anyway.  I hope that helps.  Thanks in advance, by the way.

Context is important to see exactly how and where you are calling the function. I see now where/how you are calling your function, but you're not saving the result of the function to a variable. Try errors = checkFormErrors(addobj.addReference, "#addReferenceError", errors); to update errors.

@mykaf - bro, you are a genius.  Your solution worked.  I've always wanted to be better at creating customer functions, and I think you have led me towards being a better programmer.  Thank you.  If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Not a bro, but thanks.

There seem to be be a few things going on here:

let creates a block-scoped variable, so it can only be used within the block it's declared it. You would need to create a global variable instead or pass the variable to checkFormErrors().
checkFormErrors() returns the error count, but you're not saving the result to use in your click listener. Update errors with errors = checkFormErrors(...);


Thanks again.  I'm encountering another problem, but I'll have to create another question for it.
